# Get terminal width for ssh motd?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

For my MOTD script, I've come across a need to know the width of the terminal connecting. On my computer, I (usually) have plenty of width to display my ascii banner, but on my phone, I only have `x` columns to work with (53 in this case). My script currently looks like this:

```
echo "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"\
| base64 -d \
| gunzip \
| cut -c 1-$(tput cols)
```

where `cut -c 1-$(tput cols)` works fine in all instances except the initial connection. I've also tried `cut -c 1-$(stty size | awk '{print $2}')` and `cut -c 1-$COLUMNS`. These all work when running the script from the terminal, but not when I initially connect via ssh.

It seems like the `$COLUMNS` variable isn't set until I'm connected, but is there a way to get this variable to set itself before my banner script runs?

Comment: `motd` executes before starting the login shell, so no shell variables will be defined.  However, ssh does know TERM as part of the handshake, and I believe it sets the environment variable.  You may be able to use that.

Comment: When you log n to another host by `ssh`, the terminal size certainly does not suddenly change, so you could use the `COLUMNS` value just before the connection.

Comment: you can try putting `tput col >/dev/null 2>&1` someplace in your environment before your banner script runs. Good luck.

Comment: @stark : One problem might be that `COLUMS` is not an environment variable, so on the sending side, we would have to export it and then [transfer](https://superuser.com/questions/163167/when-sshing-how-can-i-set-an-environment-variable-on-the-server-that-changes-f) it with ssh. I don't know whether the process printing /etc/motd pays attention to this variable, though.

Comment: Don't do this.  If you want the message trimmed, let the caller do it.  It is extremely frustrating when tools try to format things and wind up discarding data.  motd is not a big deal, but the principle is "keep it simple".

Comment: For example, a better way to handle this is to use a virtual terminal which is wider than the physical device, and scroll it.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I only actually want the banner trimmed, and then I'd like to use the column count for use with `fold`

Answer (score 0):

How about doing a

```
shopt -s checkwinsize
```

on the remote side, before printing the motd?

Comment: Nope, same problem as the above.

Comment: How are you actually producing the motd? Are you running your own program (and how), or you simply update the file `/etc/motd` and leave it up to the login process, to display it?